# Fill content in modal, when click on <a> tag the click event is not fired

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-modal

I try to open a modal. When the user clicks on the "Read More", the modal is launched but I need to set up the content dynamically using jQuery. In the debugger, it looks like the click is not fired, the fields aren't set up...

**Links**:

```
<a id="questionModal-13" href="#modalFAQ" data-toggle="modal" data-questiontitle="Why this?" data-questionanswer="test answer 1"> Read more</a>

<a id="questionModal-24" href="#modalFAQ" data-toggle="modal" data-questiontitle="Why that?" data-questionanswer="test answer 2"> Read more</a>
```

**Modal**:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modalFAQ">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 id="questionTitle" class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p id="questionAnswer" >Here settings can be configured...</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"><?php echo _('Close') ?></button>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

**jQuery**:

```
jQuery('[id^=questionModal-]').on('click',function(){
    var question = $(this).data('questiontitle');
    var answer = $(this).data('questionanswer');

    $("#questionTitle").html( question );
    $("#questionAnswer").html( parseJSON( answer ) );
});
```

The modal is correctly launching nor the field in the modal. When I place a breakpoint in the jQuery on click, it's not firing...

I've also tried that form :

```
jQuery('[id^=questionModal-]').click(function(){ ... });
```

jquery and bootstrap libraries are loaded...

Some one can help me please?

Comment: Seems to work fine. https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/21353/. Also, the answer is a string so you don't need to parse it

Comment: strange... for the string, this is an example. Because I will receive html tag in it, is this the good way to parse it?

Comment: You typically use parse json to get the string version of a json object. If the underlying information is html, you need to escape the characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Bootstrap modal fires many events it can be handy to use one of them instead of binding other events on the target click.

If your modal works, than you can be sure this events are fired.

As the documentation sates:

> This event fires immediately when the show instance method is called.
>   If caused by a click, the clicked element is available as the
>   relatedTarget property of the event.

You can use event show.bs.modal in this case like that:

```
$('#modalFAQ').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
    var question = $(e.relatedTarget).data('questiontitle'),
        answer = $(e.relatedTarget).data('questionanswer');
    $("#questionTitle").html( question );
    $("#questionAnswer").html( answer );
})
```

Comment: That's working! Thanks a lot! But, we have to use e.relatedTarget.dataset['questiontitle'] instead of e.relatedTarget.data('questiontitle')

Comment: ops! I forgot to wrap the elements in jquery objects to use the .data() function. I edited now.